# Country List in chronological order in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

For country list,I have take array from Iphone itself like from

`[NSLocale ISOCountryCodes]`

It return all country code from that I got full country name with some coding in alphabetical order.

but I want that it in chronological order to display in pickerview.

can any one help me shortest way to get country list in chronological order.

Comment: What do you mean by chronological order? The year/date of what related to the country? I'm missing something ... :-)

Comment: chronological order means one country found first in world will come first,then second founded country in world

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you want to order the countries by the date they were "founded". The following wikipedia page provides a list of countries with dates they acquired sovereignty:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_by_date_of_formation

You'll need to do some data curation on your side, create a lookup mechanism between the ISOCountryCode and a local database of "foundation" date.

Of course, the date a country is founded will be debatable by historians. That said, I'd be interested to hear if there was a NSWorldHistory class :-).

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your question is really: "How do I show a set of values, but sorted through a hidden set of values?"

And here, there are several other resources around stackoverflow...

One solution is to use NSDictionary with founded date as key and countrycode as value, sort by key

If your question is: "How do I populate a set of data to another set of data, with one to one relations", the answer is again NSDictionary, or nested NSDictionary with NSArray.

If your question is: "How do I get the founded dates to my app from country codes", then you should hit the V on MikeJ's answer.